# Filter rows in SSRS based on parameter and Field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I am new to using the filters in SSRS. But I would like to filter Accessories (Yes, No). This is a parameter with a yes and no Value which would display/ filter rows based on the field Field!class.Value= "I" or "A" accordingly.
So If the drop down is yes it should only display rows with class "I" otherwise All "I" and "A"
How would I do this in the Taxlib filters property. It is not working for me, the way I need it to.

Help would be immensely appreciated as usual! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Modified as per OP corrected logic ..**

Create your parameter Label `Yes` with value `="I"` and `No` with value `="*"`

[image]

In your table properties, filter section, click add button.

Below I am filtering `type` field against the parameter. You need to select the `class` field from the drop down list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks...Sorry made a mistake there. If its "Yes" then it should display only "I" class items. If no then it should display all "I" and "A" class Items. Sorry about that. I wouldn't do this the same then would I?