# SSRS Parameter, Specify Values Not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Within a dataset I created a Yes/No column.  I am trying to set a parameter that allows the user to select either the Yes or No's or both. For some reason, when the user selects "NO", we are getting "Yes" in the population too.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

This is how I was trying to set up the filter:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the dataset properties for the SQL code.

Comment: Yes, I can, but there are five tabs in there.  Which one are you referring to?  Query, Fields, Options, Filters, Parameters?

Comment: Query so we can see the SQL code and the parameter you are passing. Based on your question this is where you are restricting the data and it's not returning the data that you want.

Comment: No, the code works fine.  I have checked it.  It's however I have the parameters set up, it doesn't seem to listen to what is selected and brings back everything.

Comment: Here is the line of code though:      'case when Required_SLA_Date < cast(FulfillmentEventComplete as DATE) then 'NO' else 'YES' end as MetSLA,'

Comment: Where is it in your code where you are using the parameter value to restrict your data? I don't see it. Please add information to your question where/how you are using the parameter to restrict the data.

Comment: I don't have the parameter value in my code.  I am trying to set up a filter/parameter in Report Builder that allows the user to select yes/no and it produce those results for them.  Sort of like in excel when you would just want to select yes/no.  I tried setting up a parameter in the data set and had no luck. I thought I could add a parameter after I have built the dataset that just filters by Yes/No.  It doesnot seem to be working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62763/discussion-between-t-m-and-donviti).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you have not setup the Filter correctly ..

On the Group Properties you need to filter the column with your parameter.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to make it a parameter that the end user can use to filter results in the dataset

Comment: Yes, you want to filter for user. First you create the parameter for user to select `Yes` or `NO`. Second you need to use the parameter to filter the data. Have you used the parameter to filter the data that the user wants. I am showing you where to use the parameter to filter the data. I am using Visual Studio but it should be similar in Report Builder where you can get to Group Properties by right mouse click on `= (Details)` under `Row Groups` and click on `Group Properties`. In the `Group Properties` you can filter using the parameter. Hope I am clear.

Comment: Please also refer to [link for filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167922/filter-rows-in-ssrs-based-on-parameter-and-field/26168411?noredirect=1#comment41026465_26168411)

Comment: I think I do understand yes, however it is not a group item in my report and I don't have "details" in the Row groups.   I need to play around with it some more I guess.

Comment: Yoiu're a rock star.  That was it.  I added a group, changed the values to say ="YES" and then set the filter to the group.  Wonderful!  thank you